# Transpose a 1D byte-wise array to a 2D array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, opencv

I am reading a 64x128 grayscale image in an array, one line at a time. Each pixel is 8-bit wide. The read operation is done in a byte addressable manner. Now I want to transpose each line and store it in a 2D array. This architecture is designed towards memory optimization on a specific device. Once the 2D array is filled, I need to read it byte-by-byte such that each of the 8 bits lie in a different row of the array. Can anyone give a sample code?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far? We are not just doing the work for you here. We help you with the problems you have with your own work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sample

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    unsigned char a[64*128];
    int i,r,c;
    for(i=0;i<64*128;i++){
        a[i]=i;
    }
    //not fill
    unsigned char (*b)[64][128] = (unsigned char (*)[64][128])a;
    for(r=0;r<64;++r){
        for(c=0;c<128;++c){
            printf("%i,", (*b)[r][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    //FILL
    unsigned char b2[64][128];
    memcpy(b2, a, sizeof(b2));
    printf("\nFill ver\n");
    for(r=0;r<2;++r){
        for(c=0;c<16;++c){
            printf("%i,", b2[r][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just [construct a Mat](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html#matthebasicimagecontainer) from your array:

```
 uchar array[w*h];
 // read bytes:
 Mat m( h, w, CV_8U, array );
```

or start with a Mat in the 1st place, and read into it's data member:

```
Mat m(h, w, CV_8U);
// read into m.data
```

if you have a 1d Mat, you can just reshape it:

```
Mat m( 1, w*h, CV_8U );
// make it 2d HxW now:
m = m.reshape(1, w);
```